# Orthogonal matrix with determinant $-1$

Tags: matrices, orthogonality

I must provide a counterexample for the statement

> If $A$ is an orthogonal matrix, then $\det(A)=1$.

I know that an orthogonal matrix may have a determinant of $-1$, but how can I find such a matrix?

Comment: Hint: Reflection

Comment: How abou tthe $1\times 1$ matrix $(-1)$?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen probably the best counter example :)

Answer (score 5):

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1 \end{pmatrix}$$
in an orthonormal basis.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the space $\Bbb R$, and the application
$$
f(x) = -x.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Take the identity matrix and interchange two columns. The resulting matrix will have determinant $-1$ and will be orthogonal.